# PrimeFaces commandButton doesn't navigate

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have this code :

Add.xhtml :

```
<h:form id="nouv">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2"> 
        <h:outputText value="Nom:"></h:outputText>
        <p:inputText value="#{ddeBean.nom}"></p:inputText>
        <p:commandButton  id="save"
                value="ajouter"    
                update=":nouv:btn"                         
                actionListener="#{ddeBean.ajouter}">
        </p:commandButton>

        <p:outputPanel id="btn"> 
            <h:outputText rendered="#{ddeBean.created}" value="#{ddeBean.message}"/>
            <p:commandButton id="btn_cr" value="add" rendered="#{ddeBean.created}" 
                    action="pool.xhtml?faces-redirect=true">
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

ddeBean.java :

```
@ManagedBean(name = "ddeBean")
@RequestScoped
public class DemandeBean implements Serializable{
    ddeDAO dao = new ddeDaoImpl();
    private String nom;
    public String message = "";
    private boolean created = false;

    public void test(ActionEvent event){
        Demande p = new Demande();
        p.setDde(this.nom);
        dao.Nouveau_dde(p);
        created = true;
        this.setMessage("saved!");
    }
}
```

When I click commandButton **Ajouter** the message an the commandbutton **Add** will be shown, but commandbutton **Add** doesn't redirect to `pool.xhtml`.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the button **Add**, the bean is recreated and the value `#{ddeBean.created}` then reinitialized to `false` so the button doesn't get rendered before action take place.

To fix that, you need to change the scope of your bean to `@ViewScoped`.

You should also make sure to replace

```
public void test(ActionEvent event){
```

by

```
public void ajouter(ActionEvent event){
```

if you want that your button work properly.

**Another solution**

Since you are using PrimeFaces, you could show your button by JavaScript :

```
<p:commandButton  id="save"
    value="ajouter"    
    oncomplete="panel-create.show();"                        
    actionListener="#{ddeBean.ajouter}">
</p:commandButton>

<p:outputPanel id="btn" style="display: none;" widgetVar="panel-create"> 
    <h:outputText value="#{ddeBean.message}"/>
    <p:commandButton id="btn_cr" value="add"
        action="pool.xhtml?faces-redirect=true">
    </p:commandButton>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Note the `oncomplete` attribute on the `p:commandButton`, the `widgetVar` attribute on the `p:panel` and the `rendered` attributes removed.

Comment: When I changed the scope to @ViewScoped I had an error and my xhtm page isn't displyaed any more

Comment: yes, I have this error : Grave: Error Rendering View[/Add.xhtml]

Comment: You should append this to the question, also I'm sure there is more than one error line.

Comment: I've tested and except method `test()` that has to be renamed by `ajouter()`, getters/setters and `getNom()`, everything works fine once the scope changed.

Comment: unfortunately no I'm looking for another solution

Comment: @joice Updated the answer with a second solution.